# wrong icon in material angular stepper

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to put a edit icon when a state is "address", but the icon is the must of the first state (home).

I try:

**First step:**

```
<ng-template matStepperIcon="edit">
            <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
          </ng-template>

          <mat-step label="Antes de começar..." state="home">
..........
```

**Second step:**

```
<ng-template matStepperIcon="address">
    <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
</ng-template>

<mat-step label="Dados do seu pet..." [stepControl]="secondFormGroup" state="address">    
        <div>
            <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
            <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
        </div>
```

This is showing:

[image]

The second step must be a edit icon but have the icon of the first step why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be overriding the `home` icon, change `matStepperIcon="address"` to the following.

```
<ng-template matStepperIcon="home">
    <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
</ng-template>
```

**Revision**

You will need to control the icon override by state, please review the `phone` and `chat` states in the below material stackblitz example.

https://stackblitz.com/angular/onvqbjrynkj?file=app%2Fstepper-states-example.html

**Revision 2**

You could also use *ngIf based on index.

```
<ng-template matStepperIcon="edit" let-index="index">
            <mat-icon *ngIf="index == 0">home</mat-icon>
            <mat-icon *ngIf="index == 1">edit</mat-icon>
          </ng-template>
```

Comment: I change to the following code, but the icon still is a home in a second step

Comment: please see revision

Comment: I just tried this too..
Changed the  <mat-step state="home" label="Antes de começar..."> and <mat-step state="address" label="Dados do seu pet..." [stepControl]="secondFormGroup">

and before the </mat-step>  i put:

          <ng-template matStepperIcon="home">
              <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template matStepperIcon="address">
              <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
          </ng-template>

Comment: still dont work. i see that in this tutorial they import {MAT_STEPPER_GLOBAL_OPTIONS} from '@angular/cdk/stepper';

but if i try to import, i receive:

    [ts] Module '"c:/Users/renaotpls/Documents/git clone/cade-meu-pet-frontend/node_modules/@angular/cdk/stepper"' has no exported member 'MAT_STEPPER_GLOBAL_OPTIONS'.

my angular material is actualy in the latest version. i do no what i have to do.

Comment: please also see revision 2